# Adding a background image to Gnuplot

Tags: background-image, gnuplot

I want to put a jpg image as background for a gnuplot output file.
The goal is to have a nice looking web based weather station.

Right now I'm using gnuplot png output with transparent background setting and then setting a background image in the html code. But the result looks funky around the text. Check out the current state at :

```
http://drgert.dyndns.ws:8000/bmp085/bmp085.php
```

So I was thinking it might be better to set the background in gnuplot itself. I can set a background using a rectangle object to cover the plot area. But is it possible to use a jpg in that rectangle?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could add a background image to the plot like shown in [Gnuplot image on axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18402578/2604213), but with `filetype=jpg`. But that wouldn't look like you showed in your link, but would be only inside the graph.

You actual problem is, that the `png` terminal, which uses `libgd`, seems to have problems to render the transparency when anti-aliasing the fonts. You can use the `pngcairo` terminal, which doesn't have this problem, see the following example:

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent
set output 'transparent.png'
plot sin(x)
set output
```