# Can I plot some points over an image?

Tags: gnuplot

I wanted to get a scatter plot but the constraint is to plot these points over an image with same dimension as the range of points. Is is possible? If yes which library is good to start with? I tried using gnuplot but it is causing problems. For now I have a code which was stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583748/adding-a-background-image-to-gnuplot) but didn't work. I tried using a bitmap image with the points to be plotted in data1.dat file and used the gnuplot script which is stated in the link

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent
set output 'Figure1.bmp'
plot "Co_ordinates0.dat"
set output
```

Comment: Could you state why it didn't work and what problems you faced? This is what you should post in order to get good responses

Comment: Of course that doesn't work, that question was about transparency to include the background image via html. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18740939/2604213

Comment: Thanks @Christoph that works on jpg files but I need to include bmp image extension. is that possible?

Comment: You must convert BMP to PNG, then you can use that