# Application of Gnuplot figure as transparent on top of image

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I would like plot on the top of png figure as transparent and no axes in Gnuplot. If legend can be fitted there, it would be great.
Its code which is based on many discussions of mine in gnuplot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A54964%20gnuplot)

```
set xrange [2014:2050]; set yrange [40:125]; set datafile separator " -"; 
set key autotitle columnhead; 
set terminal qt size 560,270;  
set offset 1,1,0,0; d(x) = -0.504 * x + 1097.984; 
c(x) = 83.3; inc(x) = 0.439 * x - 800.65; 
plot d(x) t "Decreasing -0.5\%/yr", c(x), inc(x) t "Increasing +0.5\%/yr", for [i=2:6:2] "model1_range_linear.dat" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerror;
```

which produces this figure

[image]

which I want to be applied in this Figure at (2014, 83.3) or just hit starting point approximately. 
Source of the figure: *Energy visions for Finland 2030, VTT* and p. 25 [here](http://www.vtt.fi/files/projects/energy_book_series/ev_2030_tiivistelma.pdf).

[image]

### Attempt based on Christoph's comment and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18402578/54964).

Readable code

```
set terminal qt size 560,270; 
set margins 0,0,0,0;
set multiplot; 

# Just plotting here 
set xrange [2014:2050]; 
set yrange [40:125]; 
set datafile separator " -"; 
set key autotitle columnhead;  
set offset 1,1,0,0; 
d(x) = -0.504 * x + 1097.984; 
c(x) = 83.3; inc(x) = 0.439 * x - 800.65; 
plot d(x) t "Decreasing -0.5\%/yr", c(x), inc(x) t "Increasing +0.5\%/yr", for [i=2:6:2] "model1_range_linear.dat" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerror; 

set tmargin at screen 0.2; 
set bmargin at screen 0.15; 
unset border; unset tics; 
unset key;  
set autoscale xy; 
plot 'kulutus_energia_suomi_90_30.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage; 
unset multiplot;
```

where the picture is *kulutus_energia_suomi_90_30.png*, the same as in the body.

Wanted output draft

[image]

One-liner

```
set terminal qt size 560,270; set margins 0,0,0,0; set multiplot; set xrange [2014:2050]; set yrange [40:125]; set datafile separator " -"; set key autotitle columnhead; set offset 1,1,0,0; d(x) = -0.504 * x + 1097.984; c(x) = 83.3; inc(x) = 0.439 * x - 800.65; plot d(x) t "Decreasing -0.5\%/yr", c(x), inc(x) t "Increasing +0.5\%/yr", for [i=2:6:2] "model1_range_linear.dat" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerror; set tmargin at screen 0.2; set bmargin at screen 0.15; unset border; unset tics; unset key; set autoscale xy; plot 'kulutus_energia_suomi_90_30.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage; unset multiplot;
```

I get

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18402578/2604213 to get started. You must, in multiplot mode, first plot the png with margins set to zero, and then plot on top of this your lines, where you must manually fit your ranges and plotting area to the one of the background image.

Comment: @Christoph Please, see my attempt in the body. How can you make make background to burn through such that we could see it better? Probably, some setting with the plot should be changed.

Comment: I'm still not sure, what exactly you need. From the few details you give, I would think, that the resulting image should be the original png with only your additional lines. But: your xrange is from 2014 to 2050, the png goes from 1990 to 2030. Should the lines go only from 2014 to 2030 then? Then you would use the axis labels and tics from the png. Is 1990 the leftmost border, or in the middle of the left border and the second tic? Or, second variant, should only parts of the original image be extracted and plotted inside of the plot borders you generate with gnuplot?

Comment: I added the wanted output there. Clear now?

Comment: This question and answer is hardly understandable and useful to anyone else. Could you try to remove all the unnecessary stuff that is only specific to your particular case? I understand you just want a plot with transparent background, no axes or legend, on top of an arbitrary png picture?

Comment: @KarlRatzsch Thank you for your comment! I simplified the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here you go.

The steps I did where:

1. Plot the png as full-size background image (I choose the terminal window size to be exactly that of the original image):

   ```
   set terminal qt size 845,578

   set multiplot

   # plot the png as full-size background image
   set margins 0,0,0,0
   set autoscale xfix
   set autoscale yfix
   plot 'kulutus_energia_suomi_90_30.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage
   ```
2. Check the position of the plot borders in the image and set gnuplots margins accordingly, so that the xrange of [2014:2040] is located at the correct position in the image. For the yranges I used the same as in the png (top is probably 110).

The full script is

```
set terminal qt size 845,578

set multiplot

# plot the png as full-size background image
set margins 0,0,0,0
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
plot 'kulutus_energia_suomi_90_30.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage

# now plot the lines on top
height = 578.0
width = 845.0
# borders in pixel
left = 50.0
right = 646.0
top  = 515.0
bottom = 96.0

set tmargin at screen top/height
set bmargin at screen bottom/height
# get the position of 2014 on the png, assumes that left is 1990 and right is 2040
set lmargin at screen left/width + (right - left)/width * 24.0/50.0
set rmargin at screen right/width

set xrange [2014:2040]
set yrange [0:110]
set datafile separator " -"
d(x) = -0.504 * x + 1097.984
c(x) = 83.3
inc(x) = 0.439 * x - 800.65
unset key
unset tics
unset border
plot d(x) t "Decreasing -0.5\%/yr" lw 2, \
     c(x) lw 2, \
     inc(x) lw 2 t "Increasing +0.5\%/yr", \
     for [i=2:6:2] "model1_range_linear.dat" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerror

unset multiplot
```

With the result

[image]

I took the data file from [Plot from two files with errorbars for Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29717519), don't know if they are the correct ones.